# How to install FTGL library on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, haskell, ftgl

I want to use the haskell FTGL binding, which need the FTGL library. There seems no binary for windows and I can't find any useful info on how to compile it. What's the easiest way to make it work?

Comment: Generally, you install the Haskell Platform, which gives you `cabal`, and then, after satisfying any C library dependencies, do a `cabal install ftgl`

Comment: What I want to know is just how to install the C/C++ library of FTGL on windows.

Comment: Have you tried [this guide](http://www.pitt.edu/~mwr12/compcorner/linuxstuff/ftgl.html)?

Comment: I'd skip FTGL and go with GLFW-b + freetype2.  Both are on hackage and tested to work on Windows, OSX, and Linux.

Comment: @JasonDagit, what does GLFW have to do with fonts?

Comment: Did you installed FTGL on Windows successfully?

Answer (score 2):

FTGL's source download comes with visual studio solution files (.sln), which can be built with visual studio to product the c/C++ .lib files.

They may be an older version of visual studio, but you can upgrade them which ever version you have.