# Linker errors (LNK2005) in Windows using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, linker, linker-errors

I'm trying to build a project in Windows using VS2012 (2010 also available) that includes FTGL, which depends on FreeType.

When I try to build my project, I see a large number of the following LNK2005 errors:

```
Error 204 error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall FTFont::FTFont(class FTFontImpl *)" (??0FTFont@@AAE@PAVFTFontImpl@@@Z) already defined in FTFont.obj  buildDir\ftgl.lib(ftgl.dll)
Error 238 error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall FTGlyph::FTGlyph(class FTGlyphImpl *)" (??0FTGlyph@@AAE@PAVFTGlyphImpl@@@Z) already defined in FTGlyph.obj    buildDir\ftgl.lib(ftgl.dll)
Error 249 error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall FTLayout::FTLayout(class FTLayoutImpl *)" (??0FTLayout@@AAE@PAVFTLayoutImpl@@@Z) already defined in FTLayout.obj  buildDir\ftgl.lib(ftgl.dll)
Error 213 error LNK2005: "protected: __thiscall FTFont::FTFont(char const *)" (??0FTFont@@IAE@PBD@Z) already defined in FTFont.obj  buildDir\ftgl.lib(ftgl.dll)
```

I built the FTGL lib using their provided msvc->vc8 solution (upgraded to vs2010). This created the following files for both debug and release:

```
ftgl_static.lib
ftgl.lib
ftgl.dll
```

Placed the libs into my vc lib directory and added them to the *Project Settings -> Linker -> Additional Dependencies* so that I have the following line:

```
ftgl.lib
glui32.lib
glut32.lib
glu32.lib
opengl32.lib
freetype.lib
%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

Don't think it matters since I don't have any unresolved dependencies, but I have the following in my *project -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Dirs*

```
$(SolutionDir)..\..\code\lib\freetype2\include\freetype2\config
$(SolutionDir)..\..\code\lib\freetype2\include\freetype2
$(SolutionDir)..\..\code\source
$(SolutionDir)
$(SolutionDir)..\..\code\lib\FTLayout
$(SolutionDir)..\..\code\lib\FTGlyph
$(SolutionDir)..\..\code\lib\FTGL
$(SolutionDir)..\..\code\lib\FTFont
$(SolutionDir)..\..\code\lib
$(SolutionDir)..\..\code\headers
%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

Tried playing with ignoring dependencies but didn't get anywhere with that. I have also tried a variety of solutions here and on other sites, including:

- [Resolving LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007312/resolving-lnk4098-defaultlib-msvcrt-conflicts-with)
- [Google Groups 'FTGL build error'](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angel-engine/YKj2ueItJwk/jHzNCdncm0YJ)
- [How to install FTGL library on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264681/how-to-install-ftgl-library-on-windows)

Prior to this problem I was seeing the LNK2019 errors described on [this gamedev topic](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/554793-solved-ftgl-problems/). That was solved by adding the lib to the additional dependencies in the project, but introduced the LNK2005 errors.

If it helps, the project builds in OS X; however, the libraries somewhat differ for Windows (dylib in OS X vs lib/dll in Win).

Can anyone help me to resolve these errors?

Comment: I may have resolved SOME of these thanks to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ab51c229-4e70-46c0-a6c2-c5dfcd0630f5/warning-c4273-myclassmymethod-inconsistent-dll-linkage?forum=vclanguage). I added the `#define MYCLASS_API __declspec(dllexport)` to ftgl.h. Now I have a bunch of LIBCD.lib LNK2005 errors. If I compile it as /MD then I get conflicts with MSVCRT.lib. If I change /MD then LIBCD.lib conflicts with LIBCMTD.lib. ARGH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you lib are generated with same `runtime library` option under `code generation`

- /MD and /MDd is for multi-threaded (debug)
- /MT and /MTd is for multi-threaded DLL (debug)

All projects that have dependency with each other should has same option.

---

Also, you might have LIBCMT confliction if import static lib that is built with /MD and /MDd. Add LIBCMT into `ignore libraries` for linker can avoid this problem.

Comment: Bingo, that did it. I'm pretty sure the glui lib was doing that. I recompiled it from source paying close attention to that and now it's all building. Thanks!